# Post multiple Request to REST API django from Array using Axios in Reactjs

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I have an Array, i want to get all values one by one from Array and post value using axios to rest-api django

In Django i have model:

```
class Cars(models.Model):
    car = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

i want to add data in my model from axios post here is my array, from this array i want to get value and add in to my model one by one on single submit,

```
let cars = [
   ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"],
   ["Toyota", "Alto", "Civic",]
]
```

i have try like this,

```
  handleFormSubmit = event => {
     event.preventDefault();
    for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
       axios.post('myURL',{
            car: car[i]
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }
    }
```

and after on submit i got **Error: "Request failed with status code 400"**,
when i make axios post outside the loop it is fine, but i want to add multiple data from an array.

Answer (score 1):

400 error means that:

> Bad Request. Your browser sent a request that this server could not
>   understand.

Try to use the forEach function in your snippet. Sth like this:

```
 handleFormSubmit = event => {
     event.preventDefault();
     cars.forEach(car =>
       axios.post('myURL',car)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you declared variable as cars and and using car in loop .

- `axios.post('myURL',{
          car: cars[i]
      })`

try this change